# Ping Input box on web server vulnerable to piped commands?

Tags: linux, apache

Scenario is this.

I have logged into a web server as admin through the Login page in browser. it has displayed me with a home page of sorts that has an input box with a button next to it saying "ping"

it essentially will ping any ip address that you input. (tested with local and external URL's)

I know for a fact the service running on the web server is running as root.

my question is this. can i put in an IP address and then pipe a command after it to elevate my privileges?

For Example... (excluding the actual ping command in actuality)

```
ping 192.168.0.1 | usermod -a -G <groupname> username

ping 192.168.0.1 | whoami
```

the command shell running the ping is running under root (99% sure of this) so in theory it should allow me to elevate a users privileges on the system? please correct me if i'm wrong.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try the ping to your machine the injected command like `ping 127.0.0.1 && ping 192.168.0.1`?

Answer (score 1):

If the command shell is running as root and User supplied input is not properly validated then it will execute whatever command you will pass  to the shell. I think there will be proper validation of the inputs passed by the users. Like when a user will enter the IPv4 address then it will be combination of integers and dots and for IPv6 it will be integer and : . So when the user will pass the value then definitely it will be validated before passing it to shell using variable.

Answer (score 0):

So after a simple test of

```
127.0.0.1 | whoami
```

It came up with the output "root"

So essentially i could do anything if i piped it in after the IP address.

For example i had a user name jason who is a normal user with no special privileges.
i was able to add him to the sudoers file with

```
 echo "jason ALL=(ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
```

After this i was able to then SSH into the machine with jason's new permissions and change the root password with

```
passwd root
```

probably the long way to go about it, but was experimenting with what i could get away with as the output of the shell on the website only output the pipe with no way to enter prompted parameters such as "new UNIX password" when changing a password etc...

Answer (score -1):

> please correct me if i'm wrong.

ok.

> I have logged into a web server as admin through the Login page in browser.

no, you havent. you have logged into a web-application onto this webserver.

> it essentially will ping any ip address that you input. (tested with local and external URL's)

IPs. you tested IPs, not URLs with "ping"

> I know for a fact the service running on the web server is running as root.

how so?

> my question is this. can i put in an IP address and then pipe a command after it to elevate my privileges?

why dont you just try it?

Comment: well you can ping "google.com" for example... so there's no restriction on input type. and i have normal user access to the linux machine running the web server and looking at all HTTPD or apache services running they are all running as root.

I'm looking more for why this would work. and the extent of which i can pipe commands in? haven't used the pipe command a whole lot